# Software to sync external HD and NAS - must work with FAT32

Tags: software-recommendation, data-synchronization, backup, nas

I am a photographer and archive my images on a NAS (LaCie Networkspace), but as this is a single point of failure I also back my images up to an external harddrive. However, when I am away from home I archive my images straight to the external hard drive.

I would like to be able to keep these devices in sync to ensure that al images are on both drives.

Looking at the "Favourite Mac software" question, I saw Carbon Copy Cloner mentioned, which unfortunately only works with HFS+ formatted drives, so I can rule that out. I have also tried LaCie's SilverKeeper software in the past, but could not get this to work correctly. As it seemed to think that there were too many errors and just stopped working each time I tried to sync.

Can anyone recommend some reliable and intuitive software for this task?

Comment: What format are you using if not HFS+? Have you looked into SuperDuper!?

Comment: SuperDuper is not FAT compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure on the ettiquette of answering your own question, but when I downloaded the Mac App store I came across [Get Backup Lite](http://www.belightsoft.com/products/getbackup/overview.php) ([App store](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/get-backup-lite/id406345582?mt=12)) which seems to be a lot better than the Intego software that comes with LaCie drives. I've tested it on a 100GB folder between an external drive and a NAS, it was slow, but that was probably more to do with it being a network drive.

There is also a Pro version ([App store](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/get-backup-pro/id406347314?mt=12)), which adds 2 way sync and encryption, which I may upgrade to in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I used the Intego sync software that comes with LaCie drives. It wasn't great, but it did the job. It is FAT32 compatible. You can get the free LaCie version [here](http://www.lacie.com/us/products/range.htm?id=10067) (version depends on the drive; you need the code that came with it). LaCie's instructional article is [here](http://www.lacie.com/support/support_manifest.htm?id=10300&article=1385).

Comment: Thanks, I've used the Intego software before, it didn't seem very intuitive, although it did work eventually.